# Regular expression to find number followed by letter

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to regex, so apologize for silly questions ;)

1. How can I identify that a string contains a number followed by a letter? For instance, in this address `"Flat 3a Butterfly Street"` I need to identify that string contains `3a`.
2. I also need to identify if a string contains word with `"-"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not that clear but I will write what I have understood. If you like to find every digit followed by a letter you can do the following:

```
    String regEx = "\\d[a-zA-Z]";
    String s= "Flat 3a Butterfly Street";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

If the string was "Flat 123a Butterfly Street", then the answer above would still return you just "3a" again. If you like however "123a" then you can change the regular expression to

```
    String regEx = "\\d+[a-zA-Z]";
```

so that you you will retrieve all digits. If a negative sign might also be available in the target string then regex might become:

```
    String regEx = "-?\\d+[a-zA-Z]";
```

Regarding your second question you should match any character other than space (\s in regex) till you find a "-" and again you will match any character other than space to get the whole word. You can try the following:

```
    String regEx = "([^\\s]*)-([^\\s]*)";
    String s= "Fla-t  3-a Butte -rfl-y Street-";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

The following example might return you words "Fla-t", "3-a", "-rfly-f", "Street-".

You can refer to [this site](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) to start learning more about regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks, the first answer is exactly what I need!

My second questions was how to find all the words containing "-";)

Comment: @Tinien I have updated the answer for the second part; please do not forget to mark the right answers as correct after you are done. This is a good habbit and it courages people to answer your questions to come in future. Good luck.